# How to filter out all Upsertable entities in successfactors using postman?

Tags: django-rest-framework, odata, sap-successfactors

I am learning about SuccessFactors employee central API's. I want to upsert entities using postman. But I cannot find any resource about how to filter out all entities which can be upserted. Is there any way to do it using postman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call $metadata (e.g. https://apisalesdemo4.successfactors.com/$metadata) and search for "sap:upsertable=true" or "sap:upsertable=false". If yes, this entity is upsertable.